# C# ASP.Net Core create unique Email field in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

can anybody help me with that. I want that my Email Field in MongoDB is always unique. So every email can only be onetime Registered.

I heard something about IndexModel but most of the posts are obselete and the code also. Here is my Code so far:

```
public class RegisterService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Register> _Registers;

    public RegisterService(IMyFinanceDatabaseSettings settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

        _Registers = database.GetCollection<Register>(settings.MyFinanceCollectionName);




    }
    public Register RegisterUser(Register userData)
    {

        //Check if Email exists
        //_Registers.InsertOne(userData);
        return userData;
    }
```

}

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_XXXXX ON {Your Table} ({Email Column});

Answer (score 0):

You can check before adding new email

Comment: i think there is no problem with performance if you get just "Email" column